# Importance function random forest to create a logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, random-forest, importance

I have created a random forest function, the dependent variable is a binary variable (either 1 or 0). When I do the importance of my random forest, it gave me the  %IncMSE. Regarding it is logistic regression, is it normal that it does not give me the error rate?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your binary variable isn't coded as a factor and that the random forest thinks you want to do regression and hence why it gave you percent increase in MSE. Code your dependent variable as a factor and you will see the error rate measured in terms of mean decrease accuracy.